# Alter the address fields of the address module like adding a placeholder

Tags: forms, commerce

I made a form with the FormAPI to update the address fields of the address module (with Drupal commerce) and it works well. But I saw a topic where you could generate the form with an address type field.

```
$form['user_adress']['address'] = [
      '#type' => 'address',
      '#default_value' => [
        'country_code' => 'FR',
        'family_name' => $user_adress_lastname,
        'given_name' => $user_adress_firstname,
        'address_line1' => $address_line1,
        'address_line2' => $address_line2,
        'postal_code' => $user_adress_postal_code,
        'locality' => $user_adress_locality,
      ],
      '#used_fields' => [
        AddressField::FAMILY_NAME,
        AddressField::GIVEN_NAME,
        AddressField::ADDRESS_LINE1,
        AddressField::ADDRESS_LINE2,
        AddressField::POSTAL_CODE,
        AddressField::LOCALITY,

      ],
      '#available_countries' => ['FR'],
    ];
```

I find the concept very interesting. I can add a default value but I can't put a placeholder for each field.

I tried with a call back and afterbuild function (as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/customers/addresses/address-entry#altering-address-field-properties-on-forms)), also with the hook but without success. My hooks and my call back function are called but I don't see a placeholder.

```
$form['user_adress']['address']['widget'][0]['address']['#after_build'][] = '::customer_customize_address';

public function customer_customize_address($element, &$form_state) {

   $element['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'HelloWorld!;
  }
```

or

```
function mymodule_customer_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    if (($form_id == 'customer_infos')) {
        $form['user_adress']['address']['widget']['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_customize_address';
    }
    dump($form);
}

function mymodule_customize_address($element, &$form_state) {

    $element['#attributes']['placeholder'] = 'HelloWorld!;
    return $element;
}
```

I also tried simple things like :

```
$form['user_adress']['address'] = [
  '#type' => 'address',
  '#default_value' => [
    'country_code' => 'FR',
    'family_name' => $user_adress_lastname,
    'given_name' => $user_adress_firstname,
    'address_line1' => $address_line1,
    'address_line2' => $address_line2,
    'postal_code' => $user_adress_postal_code,
    'locality' => $user_adress_locality,
  ],
  '#placeholders' => [
    'address_line1' => 'Adresse',
    'locality' => 'Ville',
  ],
  // ...
];
```

Do you know if this is possible and if so how?